# How to disable value when its chosen once by the user?

Tags: javascript

I want to disable a value option once a user chooses it.

For example if the user chooses (7:00 AM) then next time they go 
and click on the drop-down again the value won't be available for them to choose.
What would be the best way to do this?

```
<td> Time it will display (Please enter time format hh:mm tt):         
    <td>
        <select ID="time_used" NAME="time_used"  VALIDATE="date" >
            <option selected> Select Time</option>
            <option value="7:00 AM">7:00 AM</option>   
            <option value="7:15 AM">7:15 AM</option> 
            <option value="7:30 AM">7:30 AM</option>   
            <option value="7:45 AM">7:45 AM</option>
            <option value="8:00 AM">8:00 AM</option>
            <option value="8:15 AM">8:15 AM</option> 
            <option value="8:30 AM">8:30 AM</option>   
            <option value="8:45 AM">8:45 AM</option>
            <option value="9:00 AM">9:00 AM</option> 
            <option value="9:15 AM">9:15 AM</option> 
            <option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>   
            <option value="9:45 AM">9:45 AM</option>                    
            <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</td>
```

Comment: Are you using any Javascript libraries or just straight JS to accomplish this?

Comment: not sure where to start, i would prefer straight js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ncksllvn's answer works, but I would propose a different solution.

It's been our experience at work that disabled controls have two major drawbacks.

1. They are not sent as part of SUBMIT.
2. Users are confused by something with a border, but is not selectable.

The second issue also applies if you try to make a read only control as well.

```
<td> Time it will display (Please enter time format hh:mm tt):         
    <td>
        <select ID="time_used" NAME="time_used"  VALIDATE="date" >
            <option selected> Select Time</option>
            <option value="7:00 AM">7:00 AM</option>   
            <option value="7:15 AM">7:15 AM</option> 
        </select>
        <span id="time_used_display" style="display:none"></span>
    </td>
</td>



function disabledTimeSelect() {
    var timeSelect = document.getElementById('time_used')
    var value = timeSelect.options[timeSelect.selectedIndex].value;

    if (value === "") {
      return;
    }

    timeSelect.style.display = "none";
    var span = document.getElementById("time_used_display");

    span.innerHTML = value;
    span.style.display = "inline";
}


window.onload = function() {
  disabledTimeSelect();
};
```

**Edit**

From the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input):

*This Boolean attribute indicates that the form control is not available for interaction. In particular, the click event will not be dispatched on disabled controls. **Also, a disabled control's value isn't submitted with the form.***

Comment: Good to know about disabled inputs not being sent on submit!

Comment: thanks, but not exactly what i was looking for , it works i try it, but i would like it when the user submit the form next time they submit a form that time wont be available

Comment: See the updated answer.  BTW - that is the sort of detail that you really need to include in your question to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple:

```
// get a reference to the menu
var timeSelect = document.getElementById('time_used')

// set an onchange handler
timeSelect.onchange = function(){
    timeSelect.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled') // set the disabled attribute
}
```